# Convert unstructured mesh to structured mesh

Tags: unstructured-mesh, gmsh

I need help to know, how can I convert an unstructured 2d mesh for structured mesh? (Software Gmsh version 4.9.3).

This is my script in Gmsh.

```c
Mesh.MshFileVersion = 2.2; 

// Geometry

//Points
Point(1) = {0, 1, 0, 0.3};
Point(2) = {0, 2, 0, 0.3};
Point(3) = {7, 2, 0, 0.3};
Point(4) = {7, 0, 0, 0.3};
Point(5) = {1, 1, 0, 0.3};
Point(6) = {1, 0, 0, 0.3};

// Lines

Line(1) = {5, 1};
Line(2) = {1, 2};
Line(3) = {2, 3};
Line(4) = {3, 4};
Line(5) = {4, 6};
Line(6) = {6, 5};

Curve Loop(1) = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
Transfinite Surface {1};
```

Comment: I don't think that you can convert an unstructured mesh to a structured one, in general. What's the rationale behind wanting to do this?

Comment: in `Gmsh` the option `Transfinite` works only for planes with four corner points, here your plane has six corners so `Gmsh` throws an error.

Answer (score 2):

in `Gmsh` only planes that have four corner points could be meshed with structured meshes using `Trasnfinite` option. In your file, the plane is constituted from six points and `Gmsh` can't mesh it structured. In such cases, you should partition the problem geometry into distinct rectangles (planes with four corner points) so the `Trasnfinite` option could be applied to them. In the following code, the geometry is modeled using three rectangles:

```
lc = 0.3;
//Points
Point(1) = {0, 1, 0, lc};
Point(2) = {0, 2, 0, lc};
Point(3) = {7, 2, 0, lc};
Point(4) = {7, 0, 0, lc};
Point(5) = {1, 1, 0, lc};
Point(6) = {1, 0, 0, lc};
Point(7) = {1, 2, 0, lc};
Point(8) = {7, 1, 0, lc};
//Lines
Line(1) = {1,5};
Line(2) = {5,6};
Line(3) = {6,4};
Line(4) = {4,8};
Line(5) = {8,3};
Line(6) = {3,7};
Line(7) = {7,2};
Line(8) = {2,1};
Line(9) = {5,7};
Line(10) = {5,8};
//Curves
Curve Loop(1) = {3,4,-10,2};
Plane Surface(1) = {1};
Curve Loop(2) = {10,5,6,-9};
Plane Surface(2) = {2};
Curve Loop(3) = {1,9,7,8};
Plane Surface(3) = {3};
//
n1 = 4;
n2 = 4;
n3 = n1*5-1;
Transfinite Curve {1,7} = n1;
Transfinite Curve {2,4,5,8,9} = n2;
Transfinite Curve {3,6,10} = n3;
Transfinite Surface {1,2,3};
```

here are the resulting structured triangular and rectangular (using `Recombine 2D` option) meshes:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much,I did not know!
DO you know how can I export this mesh for python (jupyter notebook, vscode)?

Comment: You're welcome. in the GUI you can export the mesh via `File->Export` (`Ctrl+E`), or by adding the line `Save "fileName.ext";` at the end of the `.geo` script file. Details of different export mesh file formats (and other things about using `Gmsh` ) are explained in [Gmsh documentation](https://gmsh.info/doc/texinfo/gmsh.html#MSH-file-format).
You could accept this as the correct answer if your problem is solved.